# Select menu to pass variable to function to change innerhtml

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I'm making a sidebar page for an add-on in Google Sheets.

The user will select a topic from a select menu (drop down), which will then change the inner html of div to display a different help topic.

So far the variable passed along is what gets displayed. I want the contents of the variable to be displayed as html.

I was able to make this work from text links, but they took up too much space in the sidebar, so I went to a select menu.

I made a simpler sample than my actual help sidebar so there would be less code to look at:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Select a choice from the list.</p>

<select id="topic" onchange="showContent(this.value)">
  <option value="choice1">This one</option>
  <option value="choice2">the next one</option>
  <option value="choice3">Yet another</option>
</select>

<p>When you select a choice, the output should change based on the value of the variable passed.</p>

<p id="helpContent">Results go here</p>

<script>
//VARS
 var choice1 = '<ul><li>This is the first choice<li></ul>';
 var choice2 = '<ul><li>This is the second choice<li></ul>';
 var choice3 = '<ul><li>This is the, like, third choice<li></ul>';
 
 function showContent(topic) {
  document.getElementById("helpContent").innerHTML = topic;
 }
 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Israel. It had not occurred to me to put the list items in a structure like an array. I'll study this more to understand it, but it looks pretty straighforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a data structure to represent your elements, and then create them accordingly

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <p>Select a choice from the list.</p>
  <select id="topic" onchange="showContent(this.value)">
  <option value="choice1">This one</option>
  <option value="choice2">the next one</option>
  <option value="choice3">Yet another</option>
</select>

  <p>When you select a choice, the output should change based on the value of the variable passed.</p>

  <p id="helpContent">Results go here</p>

  <script>
    var choices = {
      "choice1": {
        list: ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
      },
      "choice2": {
        list: ["item1"]
      },
      "choice3": {
        list: ["item3"]
      },
    }

    function showContent(topic) {
      var currentChoice = choices[topic];
      if (currentChoice == null)
        return alert("Invalid choice");
      var newList = document.createElement('ul');
      for (var i = 0; i < currentChoice.list.length; i++) {
        var newListItem = document.createElement('li');
        newListItem.innerText = currentChoice.list[i];
        newList.appendChild(newListItem);
      }
      var sidebarContainer = document.getElementById("helpContent");
      sidebarContainer.innerHTML = "";
      sidebarContainer.appendChild(newList);
    }
    window.onload = function() {
      showContent("choice1");
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```